# Non compact bounded operator $A$ on the Hilbert space such that $\|Ae_n\|\to 0$ for an orthonormal system

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis

The Hilbert matrix $H=\{(i+j-1)^{-1}\}_{i,j=1}^\infty $ is an example of a bounded noncompact operator such that $\|He_n\|_2\to 0, $ where $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is the standard orthonormal basis in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N}).$ According to the theorems of Widom ([Thm 3.1 and Thm 3.2](https://web.archive.org/web/20180726133158id_/http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1966-121-01/S0002-9947-1966-0187099-X/S0002-9947-1966-0187099-X.pdf)) a positive definite Hankel matrix $\{m_{i+j-1}\}_{i,j=1}^\infty $ gives rise to a bounded operator if and only if $m_n=O(n^{-1}).$ Moreover the corresponding operator is compact if and only if $m_n=o(n^{-1}).$
These results are pretty advanced.

I am looking for an elementary example of a bounded non-compact operator $A$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ such that $\|Ae_n\|_2\to 0.$ As
$\|Av\|_2=\||A|v\|_2$ for $v\in \ell^2(\mathbb{N}),$ the problem can be reduced to positive definite matrices. I do not require that the corresponding matrix is a Hankel matrix.

Comment: How about taking for $A$ identity?

Comment: @Salcio For $A=I$ we have $\|Ae_n\|_2=\|e_n\|_2=1.$  More generally any nonzero  matrix constant on the diagonals does not satisfy $\|Ae_n\|_2\to 0.$

Comment: Sorry ... I thought about $<Aa,e_n>$ going to $0$.

Comment: @Salcio The condition $\langle Aa,e_n\rangle\to 0$ is satisfied by any bounded operator.

Comment: That is why I said identity would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H_0$ and $H_1$ be two infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert spaces and $H=H_0\oplus H_1$.  Let $A:H\to H$ be the projection onto $H_1$.  It suffices to find an orthonormal basis $(e_n)$ for $H$ such that $\|Ae_n\|\to 0$.

We build this orthonormal basis $(e_n)$ one vector at a time.  Having chosen $e_0,\dots,e_{n-1}$, let $K$ be the orthogonal complement of their span.  Given a vector $v\in K$ of norm at most $1$, let $v=v_0+v_1$ with $v_0\in H_0$ and $v_1\in H_1$.  For some chosen $\epsilon$ such that $0\leq\epsilon\leq\|v_1\|$, let $w_1$ be $v_1$ rescaled to have norm $\epsilon$.  Choose some $w_0\in H_0\cap K$ of norm $\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}$ which is orthogonal to $v_0$.  Let $w=w_0+w_1$.  Note that then this $w$ is a unit vector in $K$ which is orthogonal to $v_0$, $\|Aw\|=\epsilon$, and $\langle w,v\rangle=\epsilon\|v_1\|$.

Note now that if we add $v_0/\|v_0\|$ and $w$ and to our orthonormal basis, we make sure that the projection of $v$ onto the span of our orthonormal basis has norm squared at least $\|v_0\|^2+\epsilon\|v_1\|$.  Doing this repeatedly for appropriately chosen elements $v$, we can guarantee that the closed span of our orthonormal basis contains all of $H$.  Namely, fix an orthonormal basis $(f_m)$ for $H$, and in each step choose $v$ to be the projection of some $f_m$ onto $K$.  If you arrange that each $f_m$ is chosen often enough, you can make sure that the norm of the projection of each $f_m$ onto the span of $(e_n)$ gets arbitrarily close to $1$.  You can even do this while having the chosen value of $\epsilon$ in each step converge to $0$, which will make $\|Ae_n\|\to 0$.  Then $(e_n)$ will be an orthonormal basis for all of $H$ such that $\|Ae_n\|\to 0$.

Comment: Very nice idea to choose an orthonormal basis whose elements are heavy in $H_0.$

Answer (score 4):

For each $n$ let $T_n$ be the $n\times n$ matrix all of whose entries are $\frac{1}{n}$. This is a rank $1$ projection. So $T = \bigoplus T_n$ is a projection with infinite dimensional range, and hence is not compact.

If $k$ is any positive integer, then there exists an $n$, which goes to $\infty$, as $k\to\infty$, such that
$$
\|T(e_k)\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n1/n^2=1/n.
$$
So $\|T(e_k)\|\to0$.

PS: I learned this example from Nick Weaver in a different, although related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264985/if-the-diagonal-of-a-positive-operator-is-compact-is-the-operator-itself-compac

Comment: Thanks. A beautiful simple example.